# How to notify on upcoming turn google maps API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

This may be very obvious to others but I am struggling with how to achieve this and can't seem to find it in the docs or using Google, this may be down to a badly worded query.

What I am trying to do is create a Route on a map and track my progress on it as I navigate and like the navigate function in google maps send a notification of the turn when within a x number of meters, similar to voice in google maps but I just want to get the text.

Is this possible with the Javascript API v3 out of the box? If so can someone point me to the relevant documentation or tutorials

if not out of the box, can someone suggest a design pattern or some pseudo code to do this.

What I am trying to do at the moment is.

1. Get my routes in Steps ( gps & text )
2. Get the next Step ( gps & text )
3. When current location is within 10m notify
4. when current location is past notify to update to next step & repeat

This feels like I am oversimplifying it and I am also struggling with how to correctly get the distance to next step. I know I can get the distance between 2 coordinates but is the a more accurate way to do so as to avoid getting an "as the crow fly's" distance?

I am trying to do this with Google maps api v3 in an Ionic AP using the [Cordova GeoLocation plugin](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_geolocation_geolocation.md.html)

Again Apologies if this is obvious to anyone else but I am struggling to find any relevant examples. If for some reason this is not easily done with google maps I am open to other open source or free frameworks that I can access via javascript

Comment: Hi Jonnie, 
I am also facing the same issue. Will you please let me know how you have implemented the same. If can then Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no out of the box solution. You would have to use both the  [Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) and the [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/). Directions returns routes in `legs` so you can use that to determine each step and get the user's location via [Geolocation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation).

However, this might be against [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms)

> No Navigation, Autonomous Vehicle Control, or Enterprise
>   Applications. You must not use the Service or Content with any
>   products, systems, or applications for or in connection with any of
>   the following:
>
> (i) real-time navigation or route guidance, including but not limited
>   to turn-by-turn route guidance that is synchronized to the position of
>   a user's sensor-enabled device.

Comment: Thanks I actually had just found this and was about to update